# Randomize color in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, colors, uicolor

I'm trying to randomize the text color of a label in XCode with some colors I already created, I've tried different ways and this is the closest I got.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let color1 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 165/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    let color2 = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 1, blue: 200/255, alpha: 1)
    let color3 = UIColor(red: 150/255, green: 80/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    let color4 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 80/255, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1)
    let color5 = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 1, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1)

    var randomEight = arc4random_uniform(5)+1
    var randomColor:String = String(format:"color%i", randomEight)

    randomLabel.textColor = randomColor
}
```

However, the *randomColor* variable is a String and I can't transform it to a UIColor.

Comment: Note that `80/255` is `0`, not whatever you're expecting from it.

Comment: no, it actually works for me that way, I tested some colors alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all of the colors in an array, then use `randomEight` as the index in the array to get the right color. Also, you may want to check the integer division to make sure you get the right colors.

```
let color1 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 165/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
let color2 = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 1, blue: 200/255, alpha: 1)
let color3 = UIColor(red: 150/255, green: 80/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
let color4 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 80/255, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1)
let color5 = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 1, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1)

let colors = [color1, color2, color3, color4, color5]
let randomEight = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))

randomLabel.textColor = colors[randomEight]
```

Comment: Thanks Aderis, this worked for me! Just one thing, the "arc4random.." needs to be transformed to Int for it to work. *Int(arc4random_uniform(5))*

Comment: @Gabe12 Instead of hard-coding the magic number `5`, please make the code more robust and use `colors.count` instead. It needs to be converted to `UInt32` to work with `arc4random_uniform` (copypaste from my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Put the colours in an array, then select a random index, e.g.:

```
let colors: [UIColor] = [ UIColor.redColor(),
                          UIColor.blueColor(),
                          UIColor.greenColor()
                        ] // ^- replace with your own colors

let randomColor = colors[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))]
```

Note the necessary casts to work with `arc4random_uniform`. Also note that the indices start at `0`, so do not add `1` to the random number.

There is no need for the `randomEight` (why is it “eight” anyhow?), and if the single text colour is the only place you use the colour, you can even leave out the `randomColor` and assign directly to `randomLabel.textColor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let randomEight = arc4random_uniform(5)+1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 if randomEight == 1 {
    randomLabel.textColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    }
    else if randomEight == 2 {

        randomLabel.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    }

    else if randomEight == 3{
        randomLabel.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    } else if randomEight == 4 {

        randomLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
    else {

        randomLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
    return randomLabel

}
```

Comment: Technically works (after putting the relevant parts of the code in a function and ignoring the irrelevant `didReceiveMemoryWarning`/etc that you included), but hard-coding the values in an `if`/`else` is a very inelegant solution in itself. `switch`/`case` would be _slightly_ better, but only slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this oneliner ;)

```
 randomLabel.textColor = UIColor(red : CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) , green : CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)), blue : CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) , alpha : 1)
```